# Hermitian transformation of T(A) = A*

Tags: inner-products

I have a simple question in Linear Algebra -
What is the Hermitian-adjoint of the linear-transformation defined:

> Over $M_n(\Bbb C)$ space, with the standard inner product $(A,B)_{st}$ := $tr(AB^*)$
>
> $T(A)=A^*$
>
> Find $T^*$ that satisfies $(TA,B)_{st} = (A,T^*B)_{st}$ for all $A,B\in M_n\Bbb C$

Comment: Since $T^*$ is antilinear, the correct definition of adjoint would be $(TA,B) = (A,T^*B)^*$. In this case, $T^*$ is symmetric.

Comment: Are you aware that $T$ is conjugate-linear? And not linear. What is then the Hermitian-adjoint?

Comment: Guess my professor made a mistake again. Thanks guys.